# Node.js - Send large json file to Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: json, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

just wondering if anyone has a good example of migrating large json files to Google Cloud Firestore using node.js.

I have about 50k json objects that look like this:

```
{
"asgs3100lp1006rp121993": {
    "o1": true,
    "o1a": true,
    "o1b": false,
    "o2": true,
    "o3": false,
    "o4": false,
    "o5": false,
    "o5b": false,
    "o6": false,
    "o7": false
 },
 "asgs3100lp100rp101132": {
    "o1": true,
    "o1a": false,
    "o1b": true,
    "o2": false,
    "o3": false,
    "o4": false,
    "o5": false,
    "o5b": false,
    "o6": false,
    "o7": false
 },
```

And this is the function that I currently use:

```
function addOppData() {

var fs = require('fs');
var obj;
fs.readFile('./test.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(Object.keys(obj))
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (oppKey) {
        var opportunities = obj[oppKey];
        if (typeof opportunities === "object") {
            Object.keys(opportunities).forEach(function (docTitle) {
                var oppRef = db.collection('properties').doc(oppKey).collection('opportunities').doc(docTitle)
                oppRef.set(
                    {
                        status: opportunities[docTitle],
                        dateAdded: new Date(),
                        key: docTitle
                    }
                );
            });
        }
    })
});
}
```

This obviously creates a lot of writes, but also causes memory issues in node.js. Any suggestions on a better way to write a large file to Firestore?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Try [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet)  - use it to read and parse the file as a stream and save using the batch method.